# Openstack can't connect to instance via Horizon console

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, vnc, openstack, openstack-horizon

I installed Openstack on a machine with Ubuntu Server 16.04 and almost everything works fine, but when I try to connect to the Horizon console of the instance I get the error:

`Unable to load console. Please reload page to try again.`

I can ping and ssh the instances via the floating IP, so I think I have a problem with the nova.conf file. The IP of the  machine where Openstack is installed is 192.168.128.149 and floating IPs are on the subnet 10.101.0.0/24.
This is my nova.conf file:

```
[DEFAULT]
dhcpbridge_flagfile=/etc/nova/nova.conf
dhcpbridge=/usr/bin/nova-dhcpbridge
logdir=/var/log/nova
state_path=/var/lib/nova
lock_path=/var/lock/nova
force_dhcp_release=True
libvirt_use_virtio_for_bridges=True
verbose=True
ec2_private_dns_show_ip=True
api_paste_config=/etc/nova/api-paste.ini
enabled_apis=ec2,osapi_compute,metadata
novncproxy_base_url=http://192.168.128.149:5000/vnc_auto.html

[database]
connection=sqlite:////var/lib/nova/nova.sqlite

[api_database]
connection=sqlite:////var/lib/nova/nova.sqlite

[vnc]
enabled=false

[spice]
agent_enabled = False
enabled = True
html5proxy_base_url = http://192.168.128.149:6082/spice_auto.html
html5proxy_host = 0.0.0.0
html5proxy_port = 6082
keymap = en-us
server_listen = 127.0.0.1
server_proxyclient_address = 127.0.0.1
```

I followed the guide on the openstack docs that allows to connect to consoles via spice protocol, but it doesn't work. The kind of protocol is not important (vnc, spice,etc...), I just need to connect. What I would like to know is if there are some notable error in the nova.conf file.

EDIT: Do I need to install anything on the instance in order to connect vnc or is it all managed by Openstack?

EDIT2: I tried to connect to the instance novnc console via terminal with:

```
nova get-vnc-console instance_name novnc
```

but i get the error:

```
ERROR (HTTPNotImplemented): The requested functionality is not supported. (HTTP 501)
```

Comment: perhaps see https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/105473/switching-from-vnc-to-spice/

Answer (score 0):

Try to unset or edit novncproxy_base_url=http://192.168.128.149:5000/vnc_auto.html the port number is wrong.

Comment: and what is the right port number?

Comment: for vnc it is 6080 i guess you will need http://192.168.128.149:6082/spice_auto.html for spice  in novncproxy_base_url (Try to check the url in the console frame of horizon. I'm not sure novncproxy_base_url gets picked up by horizon in case of spice though.

Comment: I updated it but it still doesn't work